# UPDATE mysqli no funciona y no tira error

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo esta funcion que hace un update dependiendo de la variable $status, lo que no me funciona es el UPDATE, y no me tira ningun error, se me olvida poner algo mas?

```
function setInfoStatusProject($status, $project){
include("bd.php");
session_start();
$idEmp = $_SESSION['id'];
$today = date('Y-m-d');
if($status == 1){
    $query = "UPDATE projectInfo SET closedBy = NULL, closedAt = NULL WHERE id = $project";
}else{
    $query = "UPDATE projectInfo SET closedBy = $idEmp, closedAt = '$today' WHERE id = $project";
}

$res = mysqli_query($link, $query);
}
```

Comment: Edita la ultima linea por esto para poder debuguear: $res = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));

Comment: Ya lo puse, pero no aparece nada, y si realizo un var_dump($res), me aparece solamente true

Comment: Y si miras la base no se actualizo ningún campo?

Answer (score 0):

```
function setInfoStatusProject($status, $project){
include("bd.php");
session_start();
$idEmp = $_SESSION['id'];
$today = date('Y-m-d');
if($status == 1){
    $query = "UPDATE projectInfo SET closedBy = NULL, closedAt = NULL WHERE id = ".$project;
}else{
    $query = "UPDATE projectInfo SET closedBy = ".$idEmp.", closedAt = '".$today."' WHERE id = ".$project;
}

$res = mysqli_query($link, $query);
}
```

Fíjate en la forma de tratar las variables en los string de las querys. Espero que estos cambios de funcionen. Saludos.

Comment: tienes que mencionar que cambios aplicaste en el código

Comment: hola, creo que son bastante evidentes.

Comment: No lo son amigo, la idea de poner respuestas es que estas sean claras y fáciles de entender

Comment: De cualquier forma no me ha funcionado :(, los campos en la base de datos permiten nulos, pero si lo hago de esta forma, me populan 0 y '0000-00-00' respectivamente, revise las variables en servidor pero estan bien, no se que pudiera estar metiendo ruido.

Comment: Pablo, recuerda que lo evidente para ti puede no serlo para otros usuarios más novatos. Recuerda epxlicar toda la respuesta para que pueda valer a todo tipo de usuarios. Un saludo